# two USB touch display not recognized Linux Kernel

Tags: usb, touch

I have two USB touch display connected to separate ports.

When both are connected, only one touch display shall be active. I can monitor touch events by seeing /dev/input/eventX. Where as other touch event is never recognized and there is no event in /dev/input/..

When I connect only one touch display, both will get recognized, touch events are fired.

I know this is 100% kernel issue. Can anyone suggest how to debug.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have something configured correctly - there should be a setting telling the driver which port the device is on.  Also, what does this sentence mean? "connect only one touch display, both will get recognized" - how can both be recognized if only one is connected??

Comment: @FKinternet: Sorry I mean when I connect touch display one after the other. In both cases, both of them gets recognized.

Comment: ok, each display works by itself is what you are saying.  I still think you need to look at how to properly configure the devices so the system knows which ports they are on.

Comment: can I get any technical details like device tree block changes, kernel config changes.....

Comment: I have primary and secondary USB touch display. When both are connected  only one touch display gets recognised. But when only primary touch is connected, it gets recognised. When only secondary touch is connected, it gets recognised. Can someone guide me how to make both of them recognised when both are connected. It is a 
intel board. Thanks

Comment: who is the manufacturer of the touch displays? where did you get them from? what software and instructions came with them? have you installed them per the instructions? the instructions *should* include directions for setting the device identifier (i.e., port) where the display is connected. your problem is most likely due to not configuring the second display to be at a different location.  if you didn't get any software or instructions, you should probably think about returning the displays and getting ones that *do* have complete drivers and installation instructions.